# フォルダ選択ダイアログで選択したフォルダの絶対パスを取得したい

Tags: javascript, html5

下記で、ディレクトリの選択ダイアログが表示され、testメソッドでディレクトリ内のファイル名を取得することはできたのですが、
選択したディレクトリまでの絶対パスは取得する方法はないでしょうか？

◆HTML

```
<input type="file" id="dirselect" onChange="test(this.files)" webkitdirectory directory />
```

◆Javascript

```
function test(files) {
    var i;
    var res = document.getElementById("res");
    res.innerHTML = "";
    for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        res.innerHTML += files[i].fileName + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: セキュリティ上の理由で出来ないと回答は出ていますが、納得できていない感じでしょうか？参考になったのであれば回答の承認をお願いいたします。また、回答についているコメントにもありますが、参考サイトを提示していただかないと見た記憶の件については回答しかねるかと思います。…憶測の範囲ですが、その見た記憶のあるサイトは`Node.js`や`Cordovaなどフレームワーク上のJavaScript`、`JScript`などで記載されているもので`JavaScript`と混同されてたりしませんか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)はChrome拡張だそうで、[現状ではChrome、Firefox、Edgeしか対応していない](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-directory)そうです。`directory`を指定しても意味はなさそうです。
`<input type="file">`はセキュリティ上の理由でディレクトリは秘匿されファイル名のみが取得可能となっている歴史的経緯があります。ディレクトリについて絶対パスが得られないのであれば同様の理由かと思います。

Comment: sayuriさま　コメントありがとうございます！　つまり、ブラウザからダウンロードするディレクトリなどを選択するようなことはできないのでしょうか？　なにかのサイトでみたような気がしたので、できるのかと…

Comment: @kanko 私は投稿された質問文に回答しました。質問者さんが念じただけで質問されていない内容には答えようがないことをご理解ください。また「なにかのサイト」と言われても第三者にはわかりかねます。

Comment: sayuriさま　コメントありがとうございます！　サイトについては社内のものでしたので、別途確認してみます

Comment: ブラウザで出来るのは、ユーザーが指定したディレクトリ以下のファイルを読むことと、隔離された領域にファイルシステムを作って、そこの中を自由に読み書きすることです